# command link doesn't work in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, uirepeat

I have a `<p:commandLink>` inside a `<ui:repeat>` in my xhtml page, my bean scope is set to 'View'. I am using JSF2.0 with primefaces 3.4. Here is the code snippet.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.selectedJob.conversions}" var="conversion">
    <p:commandLink styleClass="contextMenuItem"
    update=":form:outputParent" immediate="true"
    action="#{bean.method()}"
    oncomplete="$('#outputFilterContextMenu').hide();">
<h:outputText value="#{conversion.convType}: #{conversion.convNodeName}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

but command link doesn't invoke the back end method. I have tried it with actionListener instead of action but that doesn't work either.
Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Is there <h:form/> as parent?

Comment: Is your backing bean called if you are not using `ui:repeat`?

Comment: <p:commandLink/> is an `ActionSource` component so it HAS to be inside an <h:form/>

Comment: Where is form tag in your page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Comment: @TapasBose yes, its a child element of h:form.

Comment: @partlov, yes my backing bean works well, I have a simple p:commandLink and that works well, it passes values to the backing bean and both action and action listener methods work well.

Comment: I have fixed this issue, but that is a temporary solution. But I am really looking forward to a more suitable solution of this problem. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

When the commandLink is inside `<ui:repeat>`, the bean, which action is called, must be SessionScoped.